# Send command to webbrowser control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a web browser control that I use to display PDFs using the native Adobe reader plugin. I want a button that will invoke the find feature of the reader (i.e. equivalent to pressing CTRL+F) in the browser.

```
private void browserSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{      
    this.browserComponent.Focusable = true;
    this.browserComponent.Focus();
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^f");
}
```

This code works, but it only brings up the find box on the second click.
Every single time, you have to click the button twice before the find box pops up.

Comment: Try to insert a Sleep between Focus and SendWait command

Comment: Sadly it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial, this worked for me:

```
this.browserComponent.Focusable = true;
this.browserComponent.Focus();

System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");

this.browserComponent.Focus();

System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^f");
```

It feels like a hack, so better solutions always welcome.

Comment: work well with responsive website.